# Format specifiers in mysql plugin for pawn language

Tags: mysql, pawn

Following is a function to commit suicide in game

```
forward killPlayer(playerid);
public killPlayer(playerid)
{
    new query[128];
    if(GetPVarInt(playerid, "commitSuicide") == 1) 
    {
        mysql_format(MainPipeline, query, sizeof(query), "INSERT INTO `kills` (`id`, `killerid`, `killedid`, `date`, `weapon`) VALUES (NULL, %d, %d, NOW(), '/kill')", GetPlayerSQLId(playerid), GetPlayerSQLId(playerid));
        mysql_tquery(MainPipeline, query, "OnQueryFinish", "i", SENDDATA_THREAD);
        SetPVarInt(playerid, "commitSuicide", 0);
        SetHealth(playerid, 0);
    }
    else
        return SendClientMessageEx(playerid, COLOR_RED, "You have taken damage during the 10 seconds, therefore you couldn't commit suicide.");
    return 1;
}
```

What does "i" do in the following line of code?

```
mysql_tquery(MainPipeline, query, "OnQueryFinish", "i", SENDDATA_THREAD);
```

... and what does "ii" do in here?

```
PlayerInfo[playerid][pAccount] += amount;
                mysql_format(MainPipeline, szQuery, sizeof(szQuery), "UPDATE `accounts` SET `Bank`=%d WHERE `id` = %d", PlayerInfo[playerid][pAccount], GetPlayerSQLId(playerid));
                mysql_tquery(MainPipeline, szQuery, "OnQueryFinish", "ii", SENDDATA_THREAD, playerid);
            }
```

Related documentation: https://team.sa-mp.com/wiki/MySQL_R40.html#Format_specifiers_2

Git repository: https://github.com/NextGenerationGamingLLC/SA-MP-Development/

Please help me understand it

Answer (score 0):

These are format specifiers, mimicking the behaviour of functions like `CallRemoteFunction` which is in turn inspired by `format`. The reason for their existence is that Pawn doesn't pass the "type" of the arguments following `"i"`, which would make strings indistinguishable from scalar values. The `i` means "integer", indicating that the following value is an integer. Likewise, `"ii"` indicates that two more arguments follow, both integers. This is necessary in order to store their values and use them again next time `OnQueryFinish` is to be called.